# eas build failed while compressing

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo, eas

I've started using react native with expo.

When trying to build the application with the command:

```
eas build --profile development --platform android
```

The build fails when it reaches **Compressing project files and uploading to EAS Build**

```
s://expo.fyi/eas-build-archive
    Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir
    'C:\Users\alok7\AppData\Local\Temp\eas-cli-nodejs\42a956b8-6863-  
    43cf-bb03-e249250926ea-shallow-clone'    Code: EPERM
- Compressing project files
```

Comment: This issue was occurring from my windows defender and windows firewall. I tried all but after the reset my pc this issue got fixed.